# Javascript Regex Match()

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I just want this function to return an int back based on a string but its not working
It will be either H or V followed by 1 or 2 digits.

```
IE: H1         return 99
    H09        return 91
    H10        return 90
    H50        return 50
    V1         return 1
    V05        return 5
    V11        return 11
    V50        return 50
```

spot will be my string thats going in.

```
get100YardVersionEugene: function(spot)
{
        var team = spot.match(/[A-Z]+/);
        var yard = spot.match(/([0-9]+)/);

        if (team == "H")
        {
            return 100-yard;
        }
        else //V
        {
            return yard;
        }
    },
```

for some reason when its V9(or H9) it breaks but when i put in V09 it works.

Can someone tell me why?

EDIT: it breaks as in... 
I have two variables start and end

so i have something like 
start = get100YardVersionEugene("V9")
and I use start and end to draw it on html5 canvas

start = get100YardVersionEugene("V9")  //doesn't draw correctly
start = get100YardVersionEugene("V09")  // draw correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"? An error? A wrong result? Which one?

Comment: And have you looked at your JavaScript console for any reported errors?

Comment: If you are concerned about performance then don't use regexp for something simple like this, rather use the String routines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your regex a little so it only checks for `H` or `V`.

regarding the number, you need to remember that `match` returns an Array, so you'll need to get the value by index. Also, you shouldn't need the capture group.

And actually, you should really just use one regex.

```
get100YardVersionEugene: function(spot)
{
     var parts = spot.match(/(H|V)([0-9]+)/);
     if (parts) {
        if (parts[1] == "H")
        {
            return 100-(+parts[2] || 0);
        }
        else //V
        {
            return +parts[2];
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping yard in `[parseInt][1]`.

```
var yard = parseInt(spot.match(/([0-9]+)/), 10);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for "H09". See my answer for the reason : match returns an array.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the match function is an array. Do this :

```
 var team = spot.match(/[A-Z]+/)[0];
```

And you also need to parse the result as int.

Alternatively, it doesn't seem like regex are really needed here :

```
var team = spot.substring(0, 1);
var yard = parseInt(spot.substring(1), 10);
return team=='H' ? (100-yard) : yard;
```

Answer (score 2):

regexp is total overkill for this. Try String.charAt() or String.substr():

```
get100YardVersionEugene: function(spot)
{
   var team = spot.charAt(0);
   var yard = parseInt(spot.substr(1,2), 10);

   ...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yzq9j/2/

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to convert your yard into number

```
if( team == H ){
 return 100-parseInt(yard);
}
```

Then might be good to check for convertion validity using isNaN method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Modified code: `spot.match(/([0-9]+)/)` is returing an array

```
function get100YardVersionEugene(spot)
{
        var team = spot.match(/[A-Z]+/);
        var yard = spot.match(/([0-9]+)/);
       console.log(team , yard );
        if (team == "H")
        {
            return 100-yard[0];
        }
        else //V
        {
            return yard[0];
        }
    }
```